# Android Studio, como coletar os dados de outras telas e mostrar na ultima tela?

Tags: android

Eu tenho um app com 5 telas,

- A primeira tela as informações básicas do usuário onde usuário insere as
  informações;
- Na segunda tela as informações sobre seus interesses;
- Na terceira tela os seus objetivos;

E assim por seguinte, queria que quando ele aperta-se na tela 4 o botão próxima tela aparece todas as informações que ele informou.

Comment: Tem duas opções de fazer. Uma seria usar `Bundle` para passar as informações entre as `Activitys` e outra seria usar `SharedPreferences`!

Comment: Onde entra o Javascript?

Comment: Opa desculpas não vi a tag `Javascript`, porém pode ficar como dica para ele, pois acho que pode ser uma alternativa!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe uma biblioteca que facilita o transporte de objetos entre as classes.

É o [Parceler](http://parceler.org/)!

Segue um exemplo:

Adicione as seguintes dependencias em seu **build.gradles**:

```
dependencies {
    …
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler:1.0.4'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.0.4’
}
```

Classe de exemplo com valores que vamos transportar de uma `Activity` a outra:

**Valores.class**

```
import org.parceler.Parcel;
@Parcel
public class Valores {
    String nome;
    String sobrenome;
    Integer idade;
    Boolean masculino;
    String rua;
    String bairro;
}
```

**Envio** :

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, Step1.class);
Valores valores = new Valores();
valores.nome = "Thiago";
valores.sobrenome = "Domacoski";
valores.idade = 32;
intent.putExtra("valores", Parcels.wrap(valores));
startActivity(intent);
```

**Recepção** :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_step1);

    if(null != getIntent().getParcelableExtra("valores")){

        Valores valores = Parcels.unwrap(getIntent().getParcelableExtra("valores"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Vou testar aqui, valeu mesmo :)

Comment: Valeu muito pela ajuda, sou muito iniciante, onde eu coloco Valores.class, é dentro do arquivo mainpage.java?

Comment: É  da tela onde você está enviando...