# Configurando imagebutton no listview

Tags: android

Como posso configurar botões dentro do listview, sabendo que ele cria um button sempre que adiciono uma image e um textview no string array

```js
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View linha = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linha_de_produto, parent,
                        false);
    ImageButton add_car = (ImageButton)  linha.findViewById(R.id.carrinhoButton);
    add_car.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               // não sei como posso falar para o button que
               //ele deve pegar o textview que esta do seu lado na listview
               // e jogar pra uma activity, activity dos itens que o cliente selecionou
        }

    });
        return linha
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue um exemplo!

```
/**
 * Criamos um ArrayAdapter com o tipo de Objeto que vamos trabalhar!
 */
class MeuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Objeto>{

    public MeuAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Pegamos o objeto que vamos trabalhar!
        // Ele de ser declarado como final para que possamos usar dentro do OnClickListener!
        final Objeto objetoCorrente = getItem(position);

        final View linha = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.spinner_adapter, parent, false);
        ImageButton add_car = (ImageButton)  linha.findViewById(R.id.carrinhoButton);
        add_car.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityModel.class );
                intent.putExtra("ID_PRODUTO", objetoCorrente.getId());
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
            }

        });


        return linha;
    }
}
```

Comment: e de que forma eu pegaria ele na outra activity? la eu formaria um listview tbm, somento com os selecionados

Comment: **getIntent().getIntExtra("ID_PRODUTO", 0)** Sendo o segundo parametro **0** um valor default! Isto deve estar dentro do **onCreate**

Comment: muito obrigado :d eu já estava perdido

Comment: Aqui tem uma outra pergunta que trata de como passar de uma Activity para outra: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131800/android-studio-como-coletar-os-dados-de-outras-telas-e-mostrar-na-ultima-tela/131842#131842

Comment: o que eu retorno dentro do getter do getApplicationContext()

Comment: Este é uma método da sua Activity! você precisa passar um **Context**

Comment: ta eu passei, agora ta dando erro no objetoCorrente.getId()

Comment: Qual erro? como está o **objetoCorrente** ? Este Objeto tem um **getId()** ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43043/discussion-between-carlos-alberto-and-thiago-luiz-domacoski).